# Remove "by" from "deleted by" in timeline

Tags: feature-request, bug, wording, timeline

It seems that the "by" word should be removed from the "deleted by" phrase in the post timeline. [E.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/384251/timeline):

> [image: by]

Since "by" is already placed in the title of the next row in the timeline table.